# Prove or disprove these statements on prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Conjecture 1: Let *p* be an odd number. Suppose that there is a positive integer *h* such that $$ 2^h \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$$ 
*p* is a prime number *iff* there exist an integer k such that $ 2^{h+kp} \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$ and $k \mid p-1.$

Conjecture 2: Let *p* be an odd number. Suppose that there is a positive integer *h* such that $$ 2^h \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$$ 
If  $k=  p-1$ and  $ 2^{h+kp}  \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$  , then *p* is a prime.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The $2^h \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$ is a canard. You have both, $2^h \equiv p+2 \pmod{p2}$ and $2^{h+kp} \equiv p+2 \pmod{p^2}$ if and only if $2^{kp} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$. If $2^a \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, then $2^{ab} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for all $b$, so both conjectures reduce to

$$p \text{ is prime} \iff 2^{(p-1)p} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting where Daniel Fischer's answer ends, if $2^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$, so $2^{n-1}=1+nk$ for some $k$, then $2^{(n-1)n}=(1+nk)^n\equiv 1\pmod{n^2}$ by the binomial theorem. But there are nonprimes $n$ with $2^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$, e.g., $n=341$, so the backward implication in Daniel's display does not hold.

You should work this through, to see if it doesn't give you a counterexample, and then report back to us.

Answer (score 0):

$p=341$ is indeed a counterexample. $$2^{571}\equiv341+2\pmod{341^{2}}$$
and $$2^{340\cdot 341}\equiv1 \pmod{341^{2}}$$